# Enthought Canopy error

Tags: python, canopy

I'm not the most computer-literate person around, so please bear. I'm using Windows 7(64bit) and have been using Enthought Canopy (v 1.3.0) with Python 3.3 for the past few months. After Windows did a system update, suddenly I can't even open Canopy due to the following error:

> Unexpected error ImportError: cannot import name umath

I installed Python 2.7.6,(removing 3.3) and am still getting the error.

I'm not sure if the Windows update has anything to do with the Canopy error message. I'm not sure why Canopy is stressing over it, `umath_test.pyd` is located where all the other python files are:

> Users\myname\Appdata\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some basic misunderstanding.

1) You can't run Canopy with an arbitrary Python distribution (e.g. Python 3.3). They can coexist, but separately, not interacting. Canopy is, above all else, a Python distribution itself (2.7.6 at present). It also includes a simple IDE (editor, ipython shell, package manager, etc).

So when you install Canopy, you have installed Python 2.7.6.

2) When you run Canopy User Python you are running *not* from the directory that you mentioned, but from:

```
Users\myname\Appdata\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\
```

which itself inherits from the directory you mentioned.

To clean up whatever strangeness has happened during your installs and uninstalls of various pythons, I suggest that you delete these directories:

```
Users\myname\Appdata\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\
Users\myname\Appdata\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\
Users\myname\Appdata\Roaming\Enthought\
```

Note that to see the AppData directory in Windows Explorer, you must set Explorer to show hidden files (Computer / Organize / Folder & Search Options / View / Advanced settings / Show hidden...)

Then restart Canopy from the Windows Start menu.